# problem in showing listview in horizontal layout?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show a list view with calendar view in a linear layout. when i am using vertical layout then list view appears but in horizontal layout the same listview disaappears. I solved the problem using relative layout, but can i do this using linear layout.here is my xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"  
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <com.exina.android.calendar.CalendarView
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/calendar" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </com.exina.android.calendar.CalendarView>
<ListView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:dividerHeight="4.0sp"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the fillviewport flag in the scrollview :

```
android:fillViewPort="true"
```

Check this link to know what fillviewport flag does: [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android%3afillViewport)